# Wordpress Meta Box overwriting Page Slug

Tags: php, wordpress

I am encountering a weird bug with Wordpress 3.8.

What I am doing is creating a meta box on the side that is a multi-select of custom post types. This is working great as I can select multiple types, save the post, and display the multiple items (in this case, call to actions) on the page.

The weird part is, when I update the page in Wordpress, the page's slug (permalink) becomes the title of the *last* call to action type in the $ctas query.

Anything sticking out here? It's happening in the `if ($ctas->have_posts()` block.

```
// Disply the selection of CTAs in a meta box
function xxxxx_calloutContent($post) {
    // Get all the callouts
    $args = array('post_type' => 'callout', 'posts_per_page' => '100');
    $ctas = new WP_Query($args);
    $assignedCallouts = explode(',',get_post_meta($post->ID, 'callouts', true));
    // Create the meta box form
    wp_nonce_field('xxxxxCallout', 'xxxxxCalloutForm' );
    if (count($assignedCallouts) > 3) {
        xxxxx_ctaErrorMessage('Only three CTAs are allowed. Please choose three.');
        add_action('admin_notices', 'xxxxx_ctaErrorMessage');
    }
    echo '<label for="calloutSelect">Choose your CTAs</label><br>';
    echo '<select id="xxxxxCTASelect" name="xxxxxCTASelect[]" multiple="multiple">';
    if($ctas->have_posts()) {
        while($ctas->have_posts()) {
            $ctas->the_post();
            if (in_array(get_the_ID(), $assignedCallouts)) {
                echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.get_the_ID().'">'.get_the_title().'</option>';   
            } else {
                echo '<option value="'.get_the_ID().'">'.get_the_title().'</option>';
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo '<option value="" disabled="disabled">No Callouts</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not safe to use WP_Query in the admin, it messes with the current `$post` severely. Switch to `get_posts()` and everything should work as expected.